# The difference between 'extra' and 'another'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

would you be interested in another class?
would you be interested in an extra class?

A teacher had agreed to teach a few classes in our school for next term. meanwhile a new class was scheduled and I want to ask him if he would like to take it. Which word is appropriate here: another or extra? what is the difference?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd probably use the word "additional", which means "more than originally expected."

Comment: Ok thanks. I haven't thought of 'additional'. I think it's better than 'extra' in this context because this class will add to the ones he already accepted

Comment: Is 'one other class' possible here? or 'one more'??

Answer (score 2):

If you ask the teacher to take another class, it *might* sound like you want him to drop one of the current classes and exchange it for this new class.

If you ask the teacher to take an extra class, it is clear that all the old ones will be kept in his schedule.

In practice, either should be fine, but you can use 'extra' for clarity.

Comment: thanks. Is 'one other class' possible here? or 'one more'??

Comment: Yes, both are possible. A natural way to say it might be "How would you feel about taking on an extra class next term?" Not so different from your first suggestion.